# How to use div by its Id in MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a new application in ASP.Net MVC (beginner) from old application which is in ASP.Net and have one query that How should I convert below line of code into new in MVC?

HTML:

```
<div runat="server" id="dvLogList"></div>
```

.cs:

```
dvLogList.InnerHtml = sb.ToString()
```

I need to set the `StringBuilder` appended `string` `html` code to as `dvLogList` `innerhtml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strongly-typed your view.

As an example I have a model:

```
class DisplayModel
{
     public string str { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I will pass this model to my view:

```
public ActionResult Display()
{
    DisplayModel model = new DisplayModel
    {
         str = sb.ToString()
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

The next step is to make my view strongly typed. To make this possible add this line to the top

```
@model DisplayModel // Most of the cases you need to include the namespace to locate the class

<div id="dvLogList">@Model.str</div> // now your model is accessible in view
```

In the end, why are we doing this? 
This one has the advantage compared to using viewbag because there are cases that we need to postback data to our controller. The values from your view were automatically binded to your model (given that you declare the model in your action).

```
// model is automatically populated 
public ActionResult Save(DisplayModel model)
{
}
```

For further knowledge, read this link I cannot spare more time to improve this answer [Strongly Typed Views](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/strongly-typed-views-in-mvc/)

Comment: This answer is a workaround as the owner asked how to write code in the div innerhtml property. Isn't it possible to dispatch data to the div innerhtml property regardless of its creation ?

Comment: @MaximeOzenne take a look on viewbags

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, make use of ViewData (or ViewBag)

```
ViewData["dvLogList"] = "whatever content you want";
```

In your view you can call the ViewData wherever you need it:

```
<div id = "dvLogList" >
        @(new HtmlString(ViewData["dvLogList"].ToString()))
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following way:

in your controller action that invokes this view:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
          ViewBag.HTMLContent = "your HTML Content";
          return View();
    }
```

In Index.cshtml view:

```
<div id="dvLogList">
      @Html.Raw("@ViewBag.HTMLContent")  /*assuming your content is HTML content not just string*/
</div>
```

Comment: `Error: Too many characters in character literal`   in Index.cshtml

Comment: Edited! use double quotes!

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
    //Controller Action 

    public ActionResult Index()
            {
                  ViewBag.HTMLContent = "Your HTML Data";
                  return View();
            }

    //View page code 

<div id="dvLogList"> 
  @Html.Raw((String)ViewBag.HTMLContent)
</div>
```